# How to check which radio button is selected if they're all runat server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some code where I need to check radio buttons, and I know how to do it all client side. Here's the markup:

```
<input type="radio" id="rbInternalUser" name="radioUserType" value="Internal" onclick="setUserType()"/>
<label for="<%=rbInternalUser.ClientID%>">Internal User</label><br />
<input type="radio" id="rbExternalUser" name="radioUserType" value="External" onclick="setUserType()"/>
<label for="<%=rbExternalUser.ClientID%>">External User</label><br />
```

And the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setUserType() {
        var userType = $("input[name=radioUserType]:checked").val();
    }
</script>
```

But I need these controls set to `runat=server` because I'm doing some code behind stuff as well:

```
<input type="radio" id="rbInternalUser" name="radioUserType" value="Internal" onclick="setUserType()" runat="server" />
<label for="<%=rbInternalUser.ClientID%>">Internal User</label><br />
<input type="radio" id="rbExternalUser" name="radioUserType" value="External" onclick="setUserType()" runat="server" />
<label for="<%=rbExternalUser.ClientID%>">External User</label><br />
```

In that case, how do I find out which button is selected? It doesn't seem like the usual `$("#<%=myControl.ClientID%>")` will work here. I've tried a few things, and this seems close:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setUserType() {
        var radioUserType = $("#<%=rbInternalUser.ClientID%>").prop("name");
        var userType = $("input[name=" + radioUserType + "]:checked").val();
    }
</script>
```

`radioUserType` is getting the client ID, but then the next line fails, saying, "unrecognized expression: input[name=ctl00$body$EditUser1$radioUserType]:checked".

What do I need to put in place of `radioUserType` to make this work? Is this possible? How can you get the name of the radio button group and then check which button from the group is selected?

Comment: Hey pal, I've really forgotten most of my frontend stuff, but does that "unrecognized expression.." error come from JQuery? If so, maybe add quotes around name="HERE" or no idea really if JQuery understands "checked" pseudo-class :)

Comment: @rostamn739 Huh, that worked. It's weird that it doesn't need the quotation marks around it the other way though.

Comment: @rostamn739 If you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @JoeM try my answer it will work for you

Comment: @JoeM feel free to accept any of them. I don't need the reps :) good luck

Comment: One of the answers explains what was wrong and how to fix it, using minimal code so the change is pretty obvious; and it's useful to future visitors who may have a similar (but not exactly the same) problem.  The other answer presents a code dump that "will work for you" with no explanation at all, and good luck finding the needle of the change in the haystack of the code.

Comment: @StephenP it is only 2 lines of code and anyone can easily find it, anyway I deleted my answer. I provided this answer because I thought he may waste his hour to find and solve bug, if he will use my code it will work for him and that will save his time also and after that comparison is not tuff as there is only 2 lines in script.

Comment: @Ansari "anyone can easily find it" ... _I_ couldn't find the change until I read Sachin's answer, which _explained_ what the problem was.  A good answer here on SO will teach you something, so you can avoid making the same error in the future, not just hand you the fix. A good answer will help future visitors, not just the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While selecting elements using css attribute selector, make sure the value you are passing are enclosed in quotes. Example:

```
$("input[name='John Doe']")
```

Notice the single quotes around the name 'John Doe'.

Therefore, you need to change the existing statement

```
var userType = $("input[name=" + radioUserType + "]:checked").val();
```

to

```
var userType = $("input[name='" + radioUserType + "']:checked").val();
```

which will solve your problem.